# Restrict user to mount with autofs

Tags: redhat, autofs

Redhat 4/5

I'm trying to centralize home directories for my users. We're not at the point to implement ldap just yet, but let's say I want all my users' home directories mounted off an NFS server. I got it all working, autofs that is, but I have one minor problem.

If Sally logs in, her home directory is mounted under /export/sally. If she runs `ls /export/sam` it'll "mount" /export/sam, but she can't read or write to it. It still shows up as a mount point if she runs df -h because she attempted to mount it via autofs. Is there a way to restrict this?

**/etc/auto.master**

```
/export /etc/auto.export
```

**/etc/auto.export**

```
*       -fstype=nfs,rw,nosuid,soft nfsserver:/export/&
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to restrict this, because of a few reasons:

1. It is possible for Sam to have a folder/file that Sally has permissions to access, so Sally accessing Sam's $HOME is not necessarilly an incorrect action.
2. The system doesn't know what the permissions on the files in the mount are, until the NFS share is mounted.

You could try something like:

```
$USER servername:path/to/exports/home/&
```

However, if Sam were logged in while Sally was logged in, Sally would still see /auto/sam.

Comment: ah ok, i noticed on our system, /export/home/sam is mapped as my /home directory (I ran pwd). However, if I list the parition, it doesn't show up. How is that accomplish?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you want to list all mounted volumes, the `mount` command does that.

Comment: I'll have to speak w/ the sysadmin who runs the production server but I noticed when I logged into their boxes, my home directory is mounted as `/export/home/sam`. If I run `df -h` I see the normal partitions (/,/tmp,/home, etc...), but no mention of `/export/...`

Comment: Probably because that 'partition' isn't an actual parition on the system you are running DF on. Try `cat  /proc/mounts`